# Changing ui-views from other ui-views with Angular UI-router

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a page with 2 ui-views, the top view has a form and some controls and the bottom view  will be changed by the top view, but defaults to displaying a few tables.

I decided to try and do this initial page all in one state, and I am wondering if this is the correct way in this  case.  The state is called "tracker" and has the views with content as described above.  When the user clicks a button in the top view, I want the bottom view to display alternate content (e.g. a map).

I can figure out how to change state "tracker" (views loaded with "controls.html" and "content.html") to a complete second state ("controls.html" and "map.html").

What I'm confused about is how would I change only the bottom view `content@tracker` between "contact.html" and "map.html" based on the button state in the top view.

The router is:

```
    (function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('pb.tracker').config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('tracker', {
      url: '/tracker',
      controller: 'TrackerController as track',
      data: {
        pageTitle: 'Parcel Tracker',
        access: 'public',
        bodyClass: 'tracker'
      },
      views: {
        '': {
          templateUrl: 'modules/tracker/templates/tracker.html'
        },
        'controls@tracker': {
          templateUrl: 'modules/tracker/templates/tracker-controls.html'
        },
        'content@tracker': {
          templateUrl: 'modules/tracker/templates/tracker-details.html'
        }
      }
    });
  });

})();
```

and the base page's html is

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row spacer-top-xl">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div ui-view="controls"></div>
      <div ui-view="content"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way out is using $broadcast and $on :

From the top view controller..

```
$scope.sendBroadcast = function() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('myAction');
}
```

and from the bottom view controller

```
$scope.$on('myAction', function() {
    //Message received      
});
```

another option may be using a service and $watch on a particular value for change.